# Description of files that are in image files folder in Yocto project and the boot sequence of Yocto linux

Tags: linux, yocto, boot

Currently I'm working on a project using yocto. I want to know the purpose of following files

```
1. boot.bin
2. core-image-****-rootfs.cpio.gz.u-boot
3. u-boot-img
4. uEnv.txt
5. uImage
6. ****.dtb
```

and want to know the involvement these files when booting and the involevement order of them when booting the yocto Linux system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please understand that the following explanation is only valid for this specific question, and neither valid nor exhaustive for generic linux boot sequences.

1. `boot.bin` is usually some first stage loader, limited in size. Only enough to make the CPU capable of loading the real bootloader.
2. ´core-image-....´ is the generate root file system. The exact name and ending differ depending on the selected image target and `IMAGE_FSTYPE` in yocto
3. `u-boot.img` is the binary of the u-boot bootloader. This is being loaded by boot.bin.
4. `uEnv.txt` is the environment file of the u-boot bootloader. This can contain preset variables or scripts, for example.
5. `uImage` this is the linux kernel binary, package in the uImage format.
6. `*.dtb` is the devicetree file that tells the linux kernel about the details of the hardware in use. It depending on the specific board, it can also be used by u-boot.

Comment: This answer was really helpful. Thank you very much